# Gradient on only certain FontAwesome 5 Icons

Tags: html, css, font-awesome-5

So I am currently using this solution which is allowing me to use gradients on my Font Awesome 5 icons: [Solution 11925: for Font Awesome 5 Icon Gradients](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/11925). But, when I use the method in this solution, it applies a gradient to all the Font Awesome 5 elements, cause it applies the SVG * fill CSS rule to all of them. I don't want to apply the rule to all of them. Is there a way to get it to only apply to some? Cause I'd like to use a separate gradient for a separate section?

Here is my CSS code:

```
svg * {
fill: url(#rg);
}
```

It is currently applying that rule to these font-awesome 5 icons, which is fine: `.fa-html5,
.fa-css3-alt,
.fa-js,
.fa-camera-retro,
.fa-pencil-alt,
.fa-sass {
    font-size: 4rem;
}`

I'd like to apply a different gradient to these icons though:

```
.fa-calendar-alt,
.fa-newspaper,
.fa-paper-plane,
.fa-searchengin,
.fa-users,
.fa-newspaper,
.fa-paint-brush, 
.fa-code, 
.fa-object-ungroup {
    font-size: 2rem;
}
```

Comment: `svg.fa-calendar-alt *{}` and so on ...

Comment: did the above selector work ?

Comment: Yes it did @TemaniAfif. I can't mark it as solved since one of the moderators marked it as a duplicate question (even though it wasn't), thank you for helping me out though. Your solution worked.

Comment: yes i agree this is not a duplicate :) i can reopen if you want ... but better remove it since you have your solution ;)